# Is catch(e) shorthand for catch(Exception e) in Java/Groovy?

Tags: java, exception, groovy, try-catch

From what I understood, `catch(e)` is the same as `catch(Exception e)` ... is this true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. According to their [style guide](https://groovy-lang.org/style-guide.html#_catch_any_exception) (which in that regard seems more precise than the [documentation](https://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#_exception_handling)):

> So instead of catching the exceptions like in:
>
> ```
> try {
>     // ...
> } catch (Exception t) {
>     // something bad happens
> }
> ```
>
> Then catch anything ('any' or 'all', or whatever makes you think it’s
>   anything):
>
> ```
> try {
>     // ...
> } catch (any) {
>     // something bad happens
> }
> ```
>
> Note that it’s catching all Exceptions, not `Throwable`s. If you need
>   to really catch "everything", you’ll have to be explicit and say you
>   want to catch `Throwable`s.

Comment: "Note that it’s catching all Exceptions, not Throwables" - That is correct but just to be clear, it is catching Trowables, just not all Throwables.  It is catching all Throwables which extend `Exception` (`Exception` extends `Throwable`).